# Cloud Firestore não consigo retirar os dados de dentro do onComplete

Tags: java, android-studio, firebase

Então meu código é o seguinte:

```
SpinnerDialog spinner;
String[] textoSeparado;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.add_item);
    resultado = findViewById(R.id.result);
    DocumentReference docRef = db.collection("Bebidas").document("Cervejas");

    docRef.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
        public void onComplete(Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {

            String texto = task.getResult().getData().toString();
            texto = texto.replaceAll("[^a-zZ-Z1-9 ]", "");
            textoSeparado = texto.split("null");



        }

    });
        resultado.setText(textoSeparado[0]);



}
```

Porém por algum motivo diz que o array n tem dados. se o setText é colocado dentro do onComplete funciona. N sei mexer direito com o firestore, alguma ideia?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A busca de dados do *Firestone* é feita de maneira assíncrona, ou seja, você solicita os dados, e quando eles "chegarem" (quando a operação estiver concluída) a parte do código que está no `onComplete` é executada. Porém, seu programa não fica travado esperando esses dados, o código segue executando. **Por isso que seu** `setText` **não está funcionando**, os dados ainda não chegaram e ele já está tentando setar o texto.